# Wine cmd terminal suddenly popup

Tags: wine, cmd

I've downloaded Mr. Robot e10 from torrents and it contain the movie but it was invalid and when I removed extension it appear as windows executable. I've run it and cmd terminal popup. Now from time to time cmd terminal poup again. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete your `.wine` folder

```
sudo rm -r ~/.wine
```

All your Wine installations will be lost, but the problem too.

While the next start of wine or a Windows program via wine, the folder will be created again.

And don't download movies from torrent sites and start the executables.

Comment: Will wine work when I'll remove that directory?

Comment: @jcubic yes, win will work. I have updated my answer.

Comment: :D  +1 for don't execute downloaded EXEs!  *;-)